# Firebase Authentication without email as username?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to use a string rather than email address as a username in Firebase?

I tried, but the `createUser` method requires it to be an email address. Is there anyway I can get around this restriction?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given that Firebase Email+Password Authentication does not verify that the email address actually exists, you can just stuff any domain at the end of your string. As long as the result is a syntactically valid email address, it will work:

```
var name = 'puf'; // TODO: read this from the form where the user enters their username
var password = 'geheim';
var email = name + '@whateverdomain.com';
ref.createUser({ email: email, password: password}...
```

Note that the user won't have a way to receive password recovery emails with this approach.

**Update** there is an example of [how to implement username+password sign-in](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/username-password-auth) in the `functions-samples` repo.

Comment: This post might not be up to date: [I found this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth?authuser=0). A 'custom' login. Does that custom not work or did it not exist when you were writing this post?

Comment: This answer is indeed ancient by modern standards. But I just added a link to a recent sample of how to implement this.